# What is the correct way to animate position using svg.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

I have created a path (which renders fine). After a few seconds I simply want this to move up **vertically**.

Following the [documentation](http://documentup.com/wout/svg.js#animating-elements/invoking-an-animation) I have been able to animate the path, but it does not move as I expect it to. **The path jumps to the right & moves diagonally opposed** to a smooth vertical transition. Here is my code:

```
    hero = draw.path(pHero).center(310,200).animate(2000, '>', 1000).center(310,100);
```

Can anyone point out what is causing this?

I've outlined this in a JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwf3Z/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path's often have an offset themselves creating biassed translations. The easiest way out is to put the path in a group.

```
hero = draw.group()
hero.path(pHero)
hero.center(310,200).animate(2000, '>', 1000).center(310,100)
```

Here's the modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Dwf3Z/1/

Comment: Thanks :) Quick question. What is the better way to animate multiple attributes? Is it to chain `.center().size()` or all in `.attr({})` Or should this be done by using `during` within the animation?

Comment: It's what you like. With `attr()` you are a bit closer to svg so you have to know what you are doing. `size()` and `move()` are convenience methods to provide a unified api between different element types. But you can chain as many methods after `animate()` as you like. The following example will move, resize and fill the element: `rect.animate().x(100).size(400, 500).cy(100).fill('#f09')`.

Comment: Understood! Thanks for the example, very helpful. I've been having a play with this approach using a path & it doesn't seem to like `size` is this because the path is within a group?